# How to switch from Sourceforge mobile view?

Tags: sourceforge

I use a 3G USB modem to access the Web from my laptop. Whenever I go to Sourceforge web site, it seems to detect that I am accessing it from a mobile network and switches to a mobile view. It very annoying. Is there a way to tell it that I want to see the norman version of the web site, not a mobile one?

Answer (score 0):

If you are with Telstra Bigpond if you load up the Mobile Broadband Maneger and click Tools > and then hold down shift and click options and then select down the bottem Manullay Select a Network and then search for it and select network ID 50501 and restart the computer and it should work.

If you can't select Search for a Network make sure you are offline.

Comment: Wow! I am actually on Ubuntu. Would you be so kind to explain why the Netword ID matters?

Comment: It's becuase Telstra has at least 3 usable networks and the best one is 50501.